# Freeform multi-language notifications

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, multi-language

We're trying to work out the best way to get Freeform to send notifications in the user's language. For example, our contact form is on a page where the first segment is the lang code (/en/, /de/, etc.). We've set the config lang to match the lang set in the URL.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take the `user_notification_template=""` parameter as an example, and your two languages: `en` and `de`. (This would work for `admin_notification_template=""` and `recipient_user_template=""` as well)

First, create two notification templates in Freeform (*Notifications* tab in the Freeform CP), one in each language. Let's call their short names `user_email_en` and `user_email_de`.

Then in your template, in either `{exp:freeform:form}` or `{exp:freeform:composer}` tags (whatever one you are using), add the `user_notification_template=""` parameter, with an **early-parsed conditional** as its value. Here are a few different ways you would use the parameter:

```
user_notification_template="{if segment_1 == 'en'}user_email_en{/if}{if segment_1 == 'de'}user_email_de{/if}
user_notification_template="{if segment_1}user_email_{segment_1}{/if}"
```

If you registered an early global variable in **index.php** (eg. `{country_code}`), you could do the same as the above, but with that variable. Eg.

```
user_notification_template="{if country_code == 'en'}user_email_en{/if}{if country_code == 'de'}user_email_de{/if}
user_notification_template="{if country_code}user_email_{country_code}{/if}"
user_notification_template="user_email_{country_code}"
```

> **NOTE**: Please make sure to use an **early-parsed conditional** and NOT an **advanced conditional** (eg. containing {if:else} or {if:elseif}, using AND/OR operators, etc). Only early-parsed conditionals can work in parameters. Please refer to the EE documentation about parse order for more details.

Comment: I don't know why I thought we could only assign notification template via the CP. Works perfectly for us as now, thanks!

Comment: You can indeed set notification templates in the CP, but you can override the setting by using the corresponding parameter in the template for `{exp:freeform:form}` or `{exp:freeform:composer}`. Glad the solution worked. :)